# pyodbc connection to Oracle database on Linux

Tags: python, oracle, pyodbc

Can anyone point me to a "free" resource that allows one to connect via pyodbc to an Oracle database?  We have a multi db environment we support.  I have DB2 and MSSQL ODBC drivers working but I cannot seem to find any information on connecting via ODBC/pyodbc to an Oracle server running on Linux.

Linux:  cat /etc/redhat-release 
CentOS release 5.5 (Final)

Python: python -V
Python 2.4.3

I found a few links to some thing call mxODBC but it appears to be a closed, commercial ($$$) solution.

Answer (score 1):

Not knowing thing one about pyodbc, I have to ask: would the oracle ODBC driver in the [instant client](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/instant-client/index-097480.html) software help you out? That's free.

Comment: Never stumbled on that page with all my google's.  I will take a look and see what's in there.